# How to get the parent innerHTML and replace it with new ul li list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an un ordered list like below. I want to select TEST2 label element and replace it's parent innerHTML with new html(ul li) using Javascript or Jquery.How to achieve the above.

```
<div id='tree'>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label title="XYZ">TEST1</label>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <label title="ABC">TEST2</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is you desired html??

Comment: it's parent innerHTML with new html(ul li) ??

Didn't understand what you said? can you please explain...

Comment: I'm trying to find label element by passing the label text as search input.once I get the element I need to grab it's corresponding immediate parent ul or li html content and replace with new html content

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i have understood your question. You can use the [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("#tree").find(":contains('TEST2')").each(function(){
     //replace this element with new element by doing replaceWith
});
```

Use [replaecWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to replace this element with whatever JS method you have